# touch event not being removed, keeps working no matter where I touch the screen

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a word search game that has tokens and users can use them to reveal the word they have to find. but my problem is after i have clicked the token i cannot highlight the word i found in the word search, instead it keeps taking a token away for every time i click no matter where on the level. I have tried token:removeEventListener but that didn't work, maybe i placed it in the wrong spot

```
function token:touch( event )
if event.phase == "began" then
if storyboard.state.score >0 then
    storyboard.state.score = storyboard.state.score - 1
    score.text = tostring(storyboard.state.score)
    clueText.isVisible = false
    answerText.isVisible = true
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( event.target )
    event.target.isFocus = true
elseif event.target.isFocus then
    if event.phase == "moved" then
        print( "user has moved their finger off the token." )
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        print( "user has used a token" )
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
        event.target.isFocus = false
    end
end
return true
end
end
menubutton:addEventListener( "touch", menubutton)
token:addEventListener( "touch", token)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your function like this:

```
function tokenTouch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if storyboard.state.score >0 then
            storyboard.state.score = storyboard.state.score - 1
            score.text = tostring(storyboard.state.score)
            clueText.isVisible = false
            answerText.isVisible = true
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( event.target )
            event.target.isFocus = true
        end
    elseif event.target.isFocus then
        if event.phase == "moved" then
            print( "user has moved their finger off the token." )
        elseif event.phase == "ended" then
            print( "user has used a token" )
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            event.target.isFocus = false
        end
    end
    return true
end
token:addEventListener( "touch", tokenTouch )
```

Comment: I used both examples supplied but now the wordfind highlighter works but the token button doesn't :/

Comment: I believe I had a typo in function's name.. Edited now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove your listener.you must add remove listener after add listener.

```
local function token(event)
                if event.phase == "began" then

                elseif event.phase == "moved" then

                elseif event.phase == "ended" then
                end
        return true
        end
        token:addEventListener("touch",token)


token:removeEventListener("touch",token)
```